# SQL: Total SUM on qty

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would you add up all the qtys of a given product being returned based on its ID.

What I have tried.

```
PRODID, ITEMDES, QTY, SUM(QTY where PRODID = PRODID ) 
as total-qty-for-each-product,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use an analytical functions:

```
select
    PRODID, ITEMDES, QTY,
    SUM(QTY) over (partition by PRODID) as total-qty-for-each-product
from
    products
;
```

This works similar to the normal `SUM` with the difference that it sums all values with the same PRODID inline. The result is the same as with the following query:

```
select
    PRODID, ITEMDES, QTY,
    (select SUM(QTY) from products p where p.PRODID = PRODID) 
        as total-qty-for-each-product
from
    products
;
```

Analytical functions are best explained [by the experts](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55).

Comment: Please see update. The link is for Oracle but the concept and even the syntax is the same in Oracle and MS SQL Server.